# EC2 instance role gets 'Unknown' error when attempting aws s3 cp KMS encrypted file

Tags: security, encryption, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I've got an `ASG` that assigns an `IAM Role` to each of the instances that join it. Therefore, each instance has the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables baked-in, which will be used upon instantiation to download and decrypt credentials that are stored in an `S3` bucket and encrypted using `KMS` keys.

So I'll have the following components:

- An `S3` bucket called `top-secret.myapp.com`
- All objects in this bucket are encrypted using a `KMS` key called `My-KMS-Key`
- An `IAM` instance role with inline policies attached granting it the ability to interact with both the bucket and the `KMS` key used to encrypt/decrypt the contents of the bucket (see below)
- A `user data` script that installs the `aws-cli` upon instantiation and then goes about attempting to download and decrypt an object from the `top-secret.myapp.com` bucket.

**The User Data Script**

Upon instantiation, any given instance runs the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update
apt-get -y install python-pip
apt-get -y install awscli

cd /home/ubuntu
aws s3 cp s3://top-secret.myapp.com/secrets.sh . --region us-east-1
chmod +x secrets.sh
. secrets.sh
shred -u -z -n 27 secrets.sh
```

**IAM Role Policies**

The `IAM` role for my `ASG` instances has three policies attached inline:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}


{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::top-secret.myapp.com"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::top-secret.myapp.com/secrets.sh"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:UUID-OF-MY-SECRET-KEY-HERE"
        }
    ]
}
```

The first policy is essentially a full-root-access policy with no restrictions. Or so I thought, but it doesn't work. So I thought it might be that I need to explicitly apply policies that allow interaction with `S3` encryption and/or `KMS`, makes sense.

So I added the second policy that allows the `IAM` instance role to list the `top-secret.myapp.com` bucket, and `LIST` and `GET` the `secrets.sh` object within the bucket. But this produced the error illustrated below.

**The (Unknown) Error I'm Getting**

```
download failed: s3://top-secret.myapp.com/secrets.sh to ./secrets.sh
A client error (Unknown) occurred when calling the GetObject operation: Unknown
```

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this error?

> **Note:** This method for transferring encrypted secrets from S3 and decrypting them on-instance works fine using the standard `Amazon S3 service master key`

Comment: So, it seems that your problem is specifically concerning the "aws s3 cp" command, and doesn't (at the moment) involve any problems with KMS. The error message doesn't suggest that there is a permission-related problem. Are you able to copy any other files (eg from a public S3 bucket)? Have you tried the `--debug` option for the AWS CLI?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, John. But it's definitely `KMS` that's the issue here. It works fine with the default `S3 SSE` key, just not with any keys I assign via `KMS`. It must be something to do with the policies attached to any given resource, but I struggle to understand those. I'll have to get back to this later this week.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was two-fold:

1. If you're using server-side encryption via KMS, you need to supply the `--sse aws:kms` flag to the `aws s3 cp [...]` command.
2. I was installing an out-of-date version of `awscli` (version 1.2.9) via `apt`, and that version didn't recognize the `--sse aws:kms` command

   - Running `apt-get remove awscli` and installing via `pip install awscli` gave me version 1.10.51, which worked.

#### EDIT:

If you're using a different KMS key than the default master key for your account, you will need to also add the following flag:

`--sse-kms-key-id [YOUR KMS KEY ID]`