# Docker Hub Private Repo Login. More secure way?

Tags: automation, docker, dockerhub, infrastructure

I've seen articles such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869415/how-to-automate-a-docker-run-from-a-private-dockerhub-repo%20this%20one) about pulling from private repos and the "best" way to do it. What I understand is, if I want to automate any infrastructure to pull my docker images from dockerhub I need to:

- Have a user I can login with.
- Save the users creds in some application that will spin up my infrastructure (be it EC2 User data, a config file for ansible, or ENV variables in some API).
- When the machine spins up it uses this user's credentials to login and place a token on the machine. All is well.

I'm wondering if there is any functionality to use application keys / tokens instead of needing to tie this to a user. It seems like it would be more secure/convenient if I could manage application keys to do have access to my user/organization's DockerHub account. Then I could yank the keys or change my password and not worry about the sky falling.

Is something like this available, coming, or is there a solution I haven't come across yet?

Thanks!